# Is this a well known vector operation, and what is used for if anything common?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

This is like summing all the entries of an outer product, or as seen from a different perspective, as summing all the inner products created by cycling through vector entries:

$$\textbf{u}, \textbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

$$ \vec{u}*\vec{v} = u_1v_1 + u_1v_2+ \cdots+u_1v_n + u_2v_1 + u_2v_2 + \cdots +u_nv_1 + u_nv_2 + \cdots+u_nv_n$$

Could have sworn there was a simple name for $*$ but I can't think of it right now.

Edit: Sorry, I meant to ask, what is this called? I thought it was a well known operation, maybe I'm thinking of something else.

Comment: This is just $(u_1+\cdots+u_n)(v_1+\cdots+v_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the array that contains all of the elements in your sum is called a **tensor product**.

If $\mathbf{u}$ is an $m\times1$ column vector and $\mathbf{v}$ is a $1\times n$ row vector, then

$$\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^\mathsf{T} =
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 & \cdots & u_1v_n \\
u_2v_1 & u_2v_2 & \cdots & u_2v_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
u_mv_1 & u_mv_2 & \cdots & u_mv_n \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Perhaps this is the root of your tip-of-the-tongue experience.

I suppose you could notate $\mathbf{u}*\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n(\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v})_{ij}=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^nu_iv_j$ but that seems a bit ‘extra’ to me.

I’ve just done a hefty amount of research using related keywords, but I have yet to find a name for the operation in question.

Comment: @Zduff I'm curious: do you think that this was what you were thinking of? Or did you just find my answer overall helpful?